# Views PHP Filter buggy for Taxonomy name

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm trying to show specific contents for specific users based on the taxonomy term.

**Variables explanation:**

```
webauth variable
```

I am using these variables to setup my PHP filter.
`$_SESSION['company'];` This will return the company name of the user. This is tested works as required.

```
taxonomy variable
```

I'm trying to get the taxonomy name based on the array format from `print_r($data);` which looks like, `$data->field_field_company[0]['rendered']['#markup']` this prints the taxonomy term present in the `array[0]`. I'm using a for loop to print all the taxonomy terms (*which has a purpose*).

**What I'm trying to achieve?**

When the `SESSION` variable matches with the `Taxonomy` variable, show  specified user related taxonomy term content.

So that user having `XYZ` company can see the content, having taxonomy entity with `XYZ` term.

**How am I trying to achieve it?**

In **view** add `PHP global Filter` and in `filter code` I'm trying to add this code:

```
$length = count($data->field_field_company);
  for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
  /** as I'm having multiple arrays I'm checking every array **/
    if(($_SESSION['company']) == ($data->field_field_company[$i]['rendered']['#markup'])) {
    /** above should be like if(xyz == xyz) **/
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
```

If this same code is written in `Fields` `Global PHP` It works fine.

```
<?php
  $length = count($data->field_field_company);
  for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
    if(($_SESSION['company']) == ($data->field_field_company[$i]['rendered']['#markup']))
    echo "hi";
    }
?>
```

Why it doesn't work at all in the **Filter criteria?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there is a `dev version` for the above issue, you may need to update if you are using the old module version.

look at the comment #38 in link below. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php/issues/1222448#comment-9852925

Where you can get the `updated version` of this module.
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php